# Smarty assign errors in a foreach loop

Tags: smarty, smarty2

Okay, this is doing my head in because it just doesn't make sense. I've got an array that is assigned from php that contains 15 strings, which looks like this.

```
Array (
     [0] => 001
     [1] => 002
     [2] => 003
     [3] => 004
     [4] => 005
     [5] => 006
     [6] => 007
     [7] => 008
     [8] => 009
     [9] => 010
     [10] => 011
     [11] => 012
     [12] => 013
     [13] => 014
     [14] => 015 
)
```

Inside my template, I'm trying to assign the padded number onto a string and output that value. Except it's not working 100%. On the first assign in the loop, the value isn't present, but on subsequent assigns, it's uses the value from the **previous loop value**.

Here's the code

```
{foreach from=$faq item="qNumber" key="qKey"}
    {$qNumber} - {$qKey} -
    {assign var="qQuestion" value="help_faqQuestion$qNumber"}
    {$qQuestion}
    <br />
{/foreach}
```

My output looks like this:

```
001 - 0 - help_faqQuestion 
002 - 1 - help_faqQuestion001 
003 - 2 - help_faqQuestion002 
004 - 3 - help_faqQuestion003 
005 - 4 - help_faqQuestion004 
006 - 5 - help_faqQuestion005 
007 - 6 - help_faqQuestion006 
008 - 7 - help_faqQuestion007 
009 - 8 - help_faqQuestion008 
010 - 9 - help_faqQuestion009 
011 - 10 - help_faqQuestion010 
012 - 11 - help_faqQuestion011 
013 - 12 - help_faqQuestion012 
014 - 13 - help_faqQuestion013 
015 - 14 - help_faqQuestion014
```

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening, cause I'm fresh out of ideas.

**UPDATE**

For some arb reason, this works and produces the correct output, but I don't understand why I can't do this in one assign line.

```
{foreach from=$faq key="qKey" item="qNumber" }
    {assign var="num" value=$qNumber}
    {assign var="qQuestion" value="help_faqQuestion$num"}
    <li>{$qNumber} - {$qKey} - {$qQuestion}</li>
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope this **EDIT** workd

```
    {foreach from=$yourarray key=yourkey item=yourvalue}
       {assign var="qQuestion" value="help_faqQuestion-$yourvalue"}                         
       <li>key :-{$yourkey} -- value:-{$yourvalue} = {$qQuestion}</li>
    {/foreach}
```

and output is like:

```
key :-0 -- value:-1 = help_faqQuestion-1
key :-1 -- value:-2 = help_faqQuestion-2
key :-2 -- value:-3 = help_faqQuestion-3
key :-3 -- value:-4 = help_faqQuestion-4
key :-4 -- value:-5 = help_faqQuestion-5
key :-5 -- value:-6 = help_faqQuestion-6
key :-6 -- value:-7 = help_faqQuestion-7
```

Comment: Not at all. The first line still doesn't have "001" appended to it and the second line still has "001" appended instead of "002" and so on and so on.

Comment: That doesn't work at all for me. What version of smarty are you using? I'm on 2.2

Comment: oops I am using 3 , you can try simple {foreach $num as $val} and assign use $val while concatenating text

Answer (score 0):

change

```
{assign var="qQuestion" value="help_faqQuestion$qNumber"}
```

to

```
{assign var="qQuestion" value="help_faqQuestion`$qNumber`"}
```

and you're fine.